# Send notification to all the devices connected to a Wi-Fi network

Tags: java, android, ios, networking, wifi

Is there any way to send a notification to the devices which are connected to a particular Wi-Fi network?

Say, I have a Wi-Fi network named "My Wi-Fi", which is not secured, that is any one can connect. A public network.

There may be N-number of users connected to "My Wi-Fi". These users can perform any kind of transaction, say online payment.

Now if I want to turn off or shut down "My Wi-Fi" router or access point, these transactions may fail.

So before shutting down, I want to send a text notification to all the users connected to "My Wi-Fi" network. (User does not have any kind of app in their device, to push the notification.)

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm guessing no. As you said, any type of device could be connected (smartphones, tablets, laptops, printers, etc) - all these devices would be running different OS's and even if the WiFi protcol being used supported such an option, it would require each OS to actually support it, for the message to be shown.

Comment: Without any application installed ..this is not possible

Comment: I've removed the Java tags as they seem irrelevant. Voted to close as "off topic", since there isn't a programming question here.

Comment: I added Java tag, so that some may understand, that I'm expecting a Java solution, that can be used on server side. Also Android tag, so that some one from Android side, who has already used/tried something like this can help out.

Comment: Yes, you can send it as a part of an HTTP packet. But they may not be able to handle it (not know what to do with it).

Comment: This is not possible currently. Cisco MSAP is one of the solutions, which I think builds upon IEEE 802.11u. I dont think any phones support this right now

Comment: Magic is one option...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no standard method of sending (pushing) a message to all devices attached to a Wi-Fi network. If there was a way, it would be easy to find the specification and point to how it is to be done. Unfortunately, it is difficult to prove the absence of something.

As you clearly realized, it would be possible to do so if an appropriate page which you control was open in a browser, or application running, on their device. You could develop a framework where users have to sign on and keep a page open, or application running, in order to connect to your Wi-Fi.

Given that you control the router, it would be physically possible for you to write code which intercepted the packets being transmitted through the router and inserted such a warning within the HTTP of pages being sent to the various connected devices. This assumes that they are using HTTP to view normal pages.  You could, of course, also insert a warning in other protocols. Depending on your jurisdiction this might be illegal, or have other legal issues. I would consider doing so to be a Bad Idea™.

Comment: It is possible , my friend developing that .

Comment: when you reach airport if you connected to wifi then you will get ads and notification without installing any app or plugin \

Comment: @MidhilajM That's a significantly limited subset of what the question was asking about. it's a more specific use-case, under limited circumstances, where some things are possible. It also is specific to using a browser, almost certainly either redirected to a different page, or over HTTP (i.e. not HTTPS). It is not just general network use. The question was asking for a universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wild suggestion, you could intercept the http request and reply with a custom http response which can display a banner saying that the router is about to be shutdown. With this any ongoing payment transactions would fail. Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @lexicore I'm not so sure about that.  Kiran's answer is short and lacks code, but suggests a solution.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I've rechecked it, you are right. It indeed does suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no uniform answers to this. It depends on if you have access to the connection list. If you have access to the AP then it simplify things easier. If not, you can attempt to send a message all 254 IP addresses: 192.168.1.[1-254].

For users who are connected using WinXP or older. You can send a message using `net send`

For users who are connected using WinVista or newer. You can send a message using `msg`

For users who are connected using Linux. You can try: `smbclient -M hostname message goes here`

For users who are connected using MAC. I have not seen this yet.

Comment: any luck for user connected using MAC?

Comment: Look at the second solution. It might be what you are looking for @ricardo: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123725/any-way-to-send-messages-to-mavericks-notification-center-from-another-machine-o

Comment: @Churk; How to do this if I have access to AP?

Comment: With access to AP, you have access to the connection list, you can check if their WINS name is on that list. It reduce the searching for the client you are looking for from 254 to maybe a few. As to messaging them, as it pointed out above, there is no standard way. I just made a few suggestions that might do the job in non standard way.

Comment: @Churk will smbclient work for Android devices?

Comment: @m8labs smbclient is not a default install for android devices. So would it work, I think you need to understand what implementation the android device is installed with if any. I don't think this is a viable solution for android or ios

Answer (score -1):

Techincally, since a "handshake" is required to access the wifi, it may be possible to expand on that process.

i.e. router/modem/brouter/bridge IPv4 IPv6, etc.
Add "Broadcast / Notify connected devices" tab.

if you can get a message from instagram about a new post, you should be able to to the same with connected devices on your network.

Just a thought.