# Android send notification to the device entering to Wifi network.

Tags: android, google-chrome, push-notification, google-play-services

Is it possible to send some notification(like some text message images etc,) to the Android device connecting to Open Wifi network from a server,  where there is no custom app installed on connecting Android device. I already found the answer [Send notification to all the devices connected to a Wi-Fi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032364/send-notification-to-all-the-devices-connected-to-a-wi-fi-network).

So my question is there any google service, or playstore service  there to accomplish such a functionality. I found that Google chrome introduce similar functionality as explained here http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/20/8454613/push-notifications-android-chrome-42-mobile-web

Will it suit for above scenario?

Comment: Down-voter please tell what wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through my lack of reputation I cant directly comment, which I normaly would do.
So an option which not 100% address your problem. But might help others in a similiar situation is the new Android [NearBy Api](https://developers.google.com/nearby/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does it require that client device should installed the application created using NearBy Api. My ultimate goal is send some message to any android device coming in Wifi range.

Comment: Sadly it requires the user to install an application which uses Android Nearby. But futher more I never heard or read of a solution which matches your special case. I mean that must be something which implemented into the os itself. And of cause into the Wlan Specification.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Then I will have to reconsider the above project scenario.