# Pushing messages to smartphones connected to a Wifi network

Tags: android, ios, download, smartphone

I'm new to mobile development and have a query: Is it possible to send a push message to all smartphones (irrespective of os/platform) connected to a Wifi network? The message would ask the smartphone user if they wish to download a file (PDF). The hurdle here is that these mobile phones need not download, or have already installed any specific app for the notification to be received. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use google FCM, but first you need to check which devices are connected to your required WIFI to know which devices to send push to.

Comment: Thanks for that prompt response @VladMatvienko, but FCM requires a client app to be installed. Is it possible to use the currently installed apps? (Usually every mobile user has one of the browsers installed: Chrome,Safari,etc)

Comment: You can't send push to the non-yourth app.

Comment: the only workaround might be to use chrome web notifications. For this you should implement it on your web site. I have no idea how it is done, as it does not relate to Android at all.

Comment: You dont require GCM or FCM to do so. but you need to have specific app installed on those devices(That is must required). An implementation of wifmanager calss that can receive the signal plus A service will be required that can make local notification.

Comment: Thank you @Amardeep. I know the usual approach but wanted to know if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score -1):

There is no standard method of sending (pushing) a message to all devices attached to a Wi-Fi network. If there was a way, it would be easy to find the specification and point to how it is to be done. Unfortunately, it is difficult to prove the absence of something.

[Send notification to all the devices connected to a Wi-Fi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032364/send-notification-to-all-the-devices-connected-to-a-wi-fi-network)